# ModalPopupExtender infinite scroll on IE9

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am using an ajax:ModalPopupExtender in ASP.NET, and when I open it in IE9 I get an infinite scrollbar on my page, the actual popup looks ok, but it triggers the host page to grow infinitely.  It works fine of IE10.  I learned that if I add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to my page it does in fact work in IE9, but doing that wrecks my JQuery controls, so I need to find another solution.

Comment: What document mode does the page load in when using IE10? Same question for IE9. You can check the document mode by pressing F12 to bring up the developer tools.

Comment: @mason IE9 renders in Quirks, I just learned that it actually works good in IE9 Standards

Comment: So that means what you have to do is figured out why it's in Quirks mode and not IE 9 Standards. Try adding this right after the head tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`. I think that will tell the browser that the page is best rendered in IE 9 Standards. Assuming no other problems, the browser should then render it using that mode and it should display properly.